# How to judge a point outside the area

Tags: geometry

I have a problem that I need to test whether a point is outside the area.

The area is 2-d and is like the following picture.

[image: area picture]

The area is firstly generated by a circle whose center is a(ax, ay), radius is r.

Then with t decreases, the circle move and become bigger whose center is a/t, radius is r/t (0< t <= 1).

The growth direction is represented by vector v (cx-ax, cy-ay)

Now, I have a point(x, y). How can I judge the point outside the area or inside the area?

Comment: Have you heard of winding numbers? If the winding number is 0, and the curve is simple and closed, then the point is outside the curve.

Comment: Are you talking about a computer program?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, this problem comes from an algorithm. I want to implement the algorithm by programming. The key to the algorithm is the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

The region is bounded by a circular arc and two rays.  Choose a point $P$ known to be inside the region.  If the point to be test is $X$, check whether the segment PX intersects the boundary by testing it against each of the three bounding curves.  If PX intersects one of them, the point is inside the region.  If not, it is outside.

It isn't clear from the question whether points on the boundary are to be considered inside or outside.  That is, whether the region open or closed, but you can deal with that.  There is also the problem of machine precision if the point is very close to the boundary, of course.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you know it's two rays and not something more irregular?

Comment: @janosch That's how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Actually you can prove that the edges are rays, provided you scale the movement of the center in the same way as the radius

Comment: @janosch Yes, that's what I thought the OP meant.